# Quickest way to redefine field in Flask-Admin for custom type

Tags: flask, flask-admin

I use Flask-Admin + SqlAlchemy + PostgreSQL. What I'm going to do is the following: I want to store timezone selected by user via this [Jquery Timezones Plugin](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Easy-Timezone-Picker-with-jQuery-Moment-js-Timezones/) as Interval in database. When user create new entry, we should guess his timezone (that's what this plugin does by default), if user edit entry - we should show its time zone.

When I used String for keeping timezone, I decided to make dirty hack - wrap my field, hide it and add another one below, which is initiated by timezone plugin.

```
rules.Container('time_zone.wrap', rules.Field('time_zone'))
```

But when I switched from String to Interval, I experienced the following error:

```
ValueError: Form <flask_admin.contrib.sqla.form.MyForm object at 0x7fe4fd967690> does not have field time_zone
```

So, it looked for me that Flask-Admin doesn't support working with field for Interval type natively. I then tried to use rules.Macro, but I'm not sure how can I pass current time_zone value via form_create_rules or how can I get it from create/macro template (that's needed in case of editing entry).

Anyway, I need the quickest way to implement it (I'm OK if solution will be not as good as possible).

Any ideas?

Comment: how did you end up solving this?